# GroIP Discontinuation

Tags: updates, geoip, geoip2

I use the GeoIP legacy code on my site. The way I'm reading [this page](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geolite2-developer-package) is that the database for that version will no longer be updated. They say to use the GeoLite2 databases and

> the GeoLite2 databases are free. However, you will need to update your GeoLite Legacy integrations to work with GeoLite2 databases.

But I can't find how to do that update. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You need to change your existing library from using GeoIP to GeoIP2. It is a new library.

Comment: By "library", do you mean the database file or the "integrations" they mention? I can see where to download the database file from but there isn't a link to the "integrations", whatever they mean by that, to work with GeoLite2 databases."

Comment: The database file is different format in GeoLite2. So you will need to have new integration or codes in order to support it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The problem is that, apparently, their site doesn't have instructions on how to do that. I've gone through most of it and there will be a link to some other page on the subject. And then on that page there will be a link back to one of the pages iI was on previously. I must be missing something.